# javascript create an object which has an options property and that proerty has a length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Problem I have a list control which may or may not be (visible) on a web page. New to jscript so:
If the control is hidden because of a user option, then the jscript error with:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
for some code which would otherwise handle the optional list control

I have a class:

```
function EmptyList()
{
this.options = [];
return this.options;
}
```

and I assign it so

```
dropdownlist = document.getElementById("<%=optionalList.ClientID%>");
if (dropdownlist == 'undefined') {
  // hidden so does not exist client side
  // give it the right type but never call it
  dropdownlist = new EmptyList();
 }
else if (dropdownlist == null) {
  // hidden so does not exist client side
  // give it the right type but never call it
  dropdownlist = new EmptyList();
 }
```

I used to have an error saying options could not be read... so this seems to be in the right direction but I thought all arrays had a length...

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't return a value in your constructor, just set `options` to `[]` like you did and that's it.

Comment: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) can return only _reference to the element_ or _null_ if element not find, so your first condition always false

Comment: What are you expecting `document.getElementById("<%=optionalList.ClientID%>")` to be?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan It's likely that the server-language will print a proper ID into that JS string. If at the JavaScript level it's still `<%=...` then there's an issue. I think the part where you access `*.length` is missing though, and that could be the important part.

Comment: @Katana314 there's no mention of anything server-side in this question... but like you, I assumed it to be so; my comment was intended to help people understand the question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the undefined  / null observation, I'll simplify the code. All code is being run client side -- there is additional code which gives the error described: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined," which I'm trying to handle by giving the EmptyList object properties which will return valid properties of a list

Comment: read my comment above. you're not using the constructor function correctly. here's a [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: Hi Amit I read your link and was no clearer at the end. However changing the definition to:                            function EmptyList()
        {
            var self = this;
            self.options = [];
            self.options.length = 0;  
        }                     solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the definition of empty object to:

```
   function EmptyList()
    {
        var self = this;
        self.options = [];
        self.options.length = 0;  
    }
```

This created (with the new key word) an object variable with both 'options' as an array property and 'length' as a property of the array. The script now runs without error and resolves options and options.length